# Magic namespace prefixes in Selenium XPaths

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xml-namespaces

The issue of namespaces has been discussed here widely, my question is about some “magic” behavior for which I didn’t find any explanation or documentation:

Let’s look at [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-XHTMLplusMathMLplusSVG-20020430/sample.xhtml) website. For the following example, let’s assume I want to extract the `h1`. The following will **not** work:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions().setHeadless(true));
driver.get("https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-XHTMLplusMathMLplusSVG-20020430/sample.xhtml");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1"));
System.out.println(element.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Yes, the dreaded namespaces. Ok, let’s add the namespace URI. XPath becomes ugly, but this one works:

```
By.xpath("//*[local-name()='h1' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml']")
```

But now I’ve seem from some old code which I wrote intuitively, without thinking too much about it, that the following also works:

```
By.xpath("//xhtml:h1")
```

How does this come? Where are those prefixes getting resolved? Obviously it must be done by Selenium itself, because if I do something like this directly within the browser, I get an error about “unresolvable namespaces”:

```
document.evaluate('//xhtml:h1', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null)
```

So, my question: Where can I find the code responsible for resolving the namespace prefixes? And are there any further “default” prefixes defined?

**[edit]** Okay, this seems to be browser or driver specific. `By.xpath("//xhtml:h1")` will not work with e.g. Firefox :-(

Comment: I think you are looking for `driver.getTitle();` ;)

Comment: @JeffC Nope, this is just an example. I'll make this more obvious.

Comment: I've always found the title tag to behave oddly when using locators but I'm not sure why. I haven't observed this with other tags... do you have other examples? Oh... and the XPath engine is specific to each driver/browser, that's why most people recommend XPath as a last resort.

Comment: Probably my example was stupid, sorry. I'm not interested in the title in particular. Let’s assume I want to extract an arbitrary element from the page. I edited the question to reflect that and replaced `title` with `h1`.

Comment: One thing I didn't realize at first is that this particular document is defined as an XHTML doc, not HTML. That may be the reason for the different behavior.